# How to make a selection button inside a multistep form wizard in Django that renders an output without proceeding to the next step?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard, django-formtools

I am new to Django and I am making a project with a multistep form using `django-formtools`. The problem is, in my step 2 form, I have selection fields that I need to pass in the backend to perform some calculations and then render the output.  The user can make changes anytime based on the output. I made an `apply changes` button which should trigger the backend process and a `proceed to next step` button if the user decides to finalize the selected changes. However, when I click the `apply changes` button, it leads me to the next step instead.

Here's my `HTML` code:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ wizard.management_form }}
  {% if wizard.form.forms %}
      {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
      {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
          {{ form }}
      {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
      {{ form }} # three selection fields
      <button name="apply_changes">Apply Changes</button>
  {% endif %}

  {% if wizard.steps.prev %}
      <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% trans '&#8249; Previous Step' %}</button>
  {% endif %}
  <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Finish' %}"> 
</form>
```

Here's my `SessionWizardView` method code snippet:

```
def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):

  context = super(StepWizard, self).get_context_data(form=form, **kwargs)

  if self.steps.current == 'step_1':
    # save step 1 data to sessions

  if self.steps.current == 'step_2':
    step1_data = self.get_all_cleaned_data()
    # if apply changes button is clicked
      data = self.request.POST.get('apply_changes')
      # process data
      # add output to context
  return context
```

I need help on how can it rightly be done. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for future django developers who encountered the same problem as me, here's the answer to my question:

1) validate the data in step 2 which is temporarily the default values of my selection fields; and
2) override the `post` method to load the current page using the `goto_step` wizard function and embed it in the `apply changes` button

[You can find the guide here :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039246/django-form-wizard-save-and-go-to-previous-step)

And then there 'ya go! Once the user clicks the `apply changes` button, the page reloads and the output is rendered in the form.

Still needs to optimize it though :D